# File Upload through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to send file in folder using javascript and my code is proper working in local machine but when i have upload the project in server this this not working

```
       var formdata = new FormData(); 
        var fileInput = $("#fileInput")[0];       
        formdata.append(fileInput.files[0].name, fileInput.files[0]);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', ControllerUrl+'Upload');
        xhr.send(formdata);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {   //This condition gone false and code is move ahead
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
```

Comment: have you checked console ? what error it showing ?

Comment: are there any errors?

Comment: no its not throw any error just condition if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) gone false and its not upload the fie

Comment: upon uploading to server, you may have missed something, or there is a problem with the file you are uploading, maybe it has a big size that what is accepted